Another Issue With ChemDraw?
Two years ago I posted issues with erroneous stereochemical assignments made by ChemDraw (CD). To date, the people at ChemDraw have not resolved the issue.
Recently, I have uncovered an error with a stereochemical assignment in isoborneol (1) at $\ce{C1}$ and in the related camphor. The core of 1, bicyclo[2.2.1]heptane, was obtained from the CD Templates menu. The 2-D structure has perspective in that bond $\ce{C1-C7}$ lies in front of bond $\ce{C4-C5}$. Accordingly, the $\ce{C10}$ methyl group would be drawn such that the perspective is maintained with $\ce{C1, C4 and C10}$ lying on an axis. CD makes the R/S assignments (S)-$\ce{C1}$, (R)-$\ce{C2}$ and (R)-$\ce{C4}$ as seen in 2. While the assignments at $\ce{C2}$ and $\ce{C4}$ are correct, $\ce{C1}$ is recognized as the (S)-configuration, as so drawn,  when it is of the (R)-configuration ($\ce{C2}$>$\ce{C7}$>$\ce{C6}$>$\ce{C10}$). Adding a dotted C-H bond at $\ce{C4}$ (3) is unnecessary to maintain the (R)-configuraion. On the contrary, The $\ce{C1-C10}$-bond requires a bold wedge to obtain the  correct (R)-configuration. Note that the a bold wedge bond does not affect the assignment at $\ce{C2}$ (Cf., 2 and 4). If you are inept at drawing structures, you will get the correct (R)-configuration at $\ce{C1}$ as seen in 6. Forewarned is forearmed! Any thoughts are welcome.


I saw similar issues with other software, too. Especially with bicyclic and bridged structures. Would it help if you drew the 6-membered ring flat, with all substituents therefore being clearly up or down? I sometimes noticed that it's better to use up/down wedges on terminal substituents, even adding H where appropriate. But yes, no software is perfect. Just one word: 'adamantane'... don't get me started on that one.

@user6376297: If you are a fan of adamantane, you mey be interested in this.

Funny, that's precisely the info I consulted to test the chemical drawing software I am using (not ChemDraw) and ended up proving that it gets it all wrong. Hence the 'do not get me started' :). From a cheminformatics point of view, the question is also whether two molecules that the software fails to assign CIP stereochemistry correctly to, will be appropriately discriminated e.g. in a substance registration system. Can of worms and all that.

There is implied wedge at C1 in structure 2 for the methyl group. I don't think you can determine stereochemistry without whole molecule context, and I would venture that ChemDraw is not being nearly fancy enough with the algorithm for assignment. That 6 is correct is likely just coincidence.
